# Returning a blank cell in MS Excel formula if 2 source cells are blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My formula in B3 is =A3+B2-B1. I want B3 to be blank if both B2 and B1 are blank also. Could anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`IF`](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) to create a condition, [`AND`](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9) because you need to match multiple conditions, and [`ISBLANK`](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/IS-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665) for your conditions:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(B1), ISBLANK(B2)), "", A3+B2-B1)
```

Answer (score 2):

To start out, first lets work with one cell. B1.

`=IF(B1="","",SUM(A3+B2-B1))`

This will return blank if B1 is empty or will do the sum. Now we can just wrap that in another if.

`=IF(B2="","",IF(B1="","",SUM(A3+B2-B1)))`

The problem with `ISBLANK` is that if there is a formula in that field, it will not return blank, even if there is no number in the field.

Comment: Good point about the `ISBLANK` function. However, no need for the `SUM`, and I think `AND` is more simple then a nested `IF` especially when wanting to check for more then 2 conditions. So I would do: `=IF(AND(B2="",B1=""),"",A3+B2-B1)`.